# php array with multiple values for json parsing

Tags: php, json

I have coded to display single array fetching from database. I want to display multiple array values as shown in below

```
{"newrelease" : [{"model" : "apple 6", "image": " photo.jpg" , "specs": ""}] }
```

I have coded `$response['New Releases' ][]['Model'][$b['PhoneModel']] =$b['FileName'];`

which gives output as `{"New Releases":[{"Model":{"desire-x":"_htc-desire-x-dual-sim.jpg"}}`

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Can you give some more information about what you are doing?

Comment: Needs more code to explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new `array` to your `newrelease` `array` like this

```
$response['newrelease'][] = array(
    'model' => $b['PhoneModel'],
    'image' => $b['FileName'],
    'specs' => ""
);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

This here should do the trick i think:

```
$response['newrelease'][] = array("model" => "apple 6", "image" => " photo.jpg" , "specs" => "");
```